# Appending data and adding a class after a successful AJAX call with response from php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to send an AJAX call to my php file to send an email after a contact form is filled out. I had this working perfectly when I was just trying to get the echo response from php and put it in my div above my form, but I wanted to append some data and add a class after it came back successful to give it a better look. Right now, with this code, the email still sends through, but the message or class does not show up.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the response from php to display in the contactSuccess div while appending everything and hiding the contactSuccess div until it has successfully come through?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){

    $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
    //test
    $('#contactMessageStatus').append(data);
    $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
     }, 2000);
    //endtest
    $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
    //$('#success').hide('slow');
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Form

```
<div id="contactMessageStatus"></div>
    <form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform" >
        <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        <input type="email"  class="inputbar" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="message"  class="inputbar" name="message" placeholder="Message" required>
        <input type="button" value="Send Message" id="submit">
    </form>
```

CSS

```
#contactSuccess {
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;
    background-position: 10px 9px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    min-height: 24px !important;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px !important;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;

    border-color: #446423;
    background-color: #eff5ea;
    background-image: url(success_check.gif);
    color: #3d6611;
}
```

PHP file - Adding this just in case

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'contact@example.com';
$subject = 'SFL Contact Form Submitted';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name. ' ' . ' Email: '.$email. ' ' . 'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: contact@example.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely to be in your $.post response handler.  One of the lines before you attempt to display the response is probably throwing an exception.  My suspicion is the line ...

```
$('#contactMessageStatus').append(data);
```

... but that is only because I cannot see where you are getting 'data' from.

Wrap that section of code within your response handler in a try / catch block and see if an exception is really causing this problem.

Comment: I commented out that line and the message goes through still and I get the echo'd info from php, but my class is not added to it.

Comment: Ah.  Just noticed your style is defined as #contactSuccess.  Try changing that to .contactSuccess.

Comment: If I do this, it breaks the code again.. `$('#contactSuccess').append(data);`

Comment: There is no $('#contactSuccess').append(data); in the code you have shown.

Comment: Sorry, completely misunderstood what you meant. I changed that to the class and added in Samir's line and it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: is there anyway I can put an else statement in the ajax call and modify this so if the response from the php statement is the else statement, that I can use a different class?

Answer (score 1):

Change $('#contactMessageStatus').append(data); to $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);

Comment: this allowed the code to go through, but my css class is now showing up with the response.

Comment: See John Sheridan comment. Your CSS file has #contactSuccess change it to .contactSuccess.

Comment: Thanks! completely misunderstood what he said. That fixed it, mixed with your answer.

Comment: is there anyway I can put an else statement in the ajax call and modify this so if the response from the php statement is the else statement, that I can use a different class?

Answer (score 0):

Have added if else statement in your script based on the response from PHP.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

    $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
    //test
    if(response == 'Your email was sent!')
    {
        $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
        $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
        }, 2000);
        //endtest
        $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
        //$('#success').hide('slow');
    }
    else
    {
        //error handling code
    }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#frm-comment").on('submit',function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                         $.ajax({
                          
                                success: function(response)  {
                                $("#showcomments").prepend(response);
                                 }
                               });
                          });
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.